# How can I set an SObject field to null using Java API?

Tags: api, force.com-sites, java

I have a third party service which updates custom object values in my service on Force.com platform using Java API and OAUTH2.

From some reason when I try to update the SObject field value to null, it ignores my request and keeps the old value. If I update it to a non-null value it does so successfully.

Here is the code:

```
         SObject quizTemplateSObject = new SObject();
         ...
         ...
        quizTemplateSObject.setField("skills__notifyList__c",null);     
        results = connection.update(new SObject[] { quizTemplateSObject });
```

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce has a "fieldsToNull" array in its update API as described in the [update](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_update.htm) documentation. Exactly how this is exposed depends on the tools used to generate the Java code from the WSDL but it is likely to be something like:

```
quizTemplateSObject.setFieldsToNull(
        new String[] {"skills__notifyList__c"}
        );
```